# Custom classification threshold for GBM

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, r-caret, gbm

I'm trying to create a custom GBM model that tunes the classification threshold for a binary classification problem. There is a nice example provided on the caret website [here](https://topepo.github.io/caret/using-your-own-model-in-train.html#illustrative-example-5-optimizing-probability-thresholds-for-class-imbalances), but when I try to apply something similar to GBM I receive the following error:

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "argument 1 is not a vector"
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea where the error is and the error isn't very helpful.

Here's an example, with the code that I've used for defining the custom GBM

```
library(caret)
library(gbm)
library(pROC)
#### DEFINE A CUSTOM GBM MODEL FOR PROBABILITY THRESHOLD TUNING ####
## Get the model code for the original gbm method from caret
customGBM <- getModelInfo("gbm", regex = FALSE)[[1]]
customGBM$type <- c("Classification")
## Add the threshold (i.e. class cutoff) as another tuning parameter
customGBM$parameters <- data.frame(parameter = c("n.trees", "interaction.depth", "shrinkage",
                                                 "n.minobsinnode", "threshold"),
                                   class = rep("numeric", 5),
                                   label = c("# Boosting Iterations", "Max Tree Depth", "Shrinkage",
                                             "Min. Terminal Node Size", "Probability Cutoff"))
## Customise the tuning grid:
## Some paramters are fixed. Will give a tuning grid of 2,500 values if len = 100
customGBM$grid <- function(x, y, len = NULL, search = "grid") {
  if (search == "grid") {
    grid <- expand.grid(n.trees = seq(50, 250, 50),
                        interaction.depth = 2, ### fix interaction depth at 2
                        shrinkage = 0.0001, ### fix learning rate at 0.0001
                        n.minobsinnode = seq(2, 10, 2),
                        threshold = seq(.01, .99, length = len))
    } else {
    grid <- expand.grid(n.trees = floor(runif(len, min = 1, max = 5000)),
                        interaction.depth = sample(1:10, replace = TRUE, size = len),
                        shrinkage = runif(len, min = .001, max = .6),
                        n.minobsinnode = sample(5:25, replace = TRUE, size = len),
                        threshold = runif(1, 0, size = len))
    grid <- grid[!duplicated(grid),] ### remove any duplicated rows in the training grid
  }
  grid
}

## Here we fit a single gbm model and loop over the threshold values to get predictions from the
## same gbm model.
customGBM$loop = function(grid) {
  library(plyr)
  loop <- ddply(grid, c("n.trees", "shrinkage", "interaction.depth", "n.minobsinnode"),
                function(x) c(threshold = max(x$threshold)))
  submodels <- vector(mode = "list", length = nrow(loop))
  for (i in seq(along = loop$threshold)) {
    index <- which(grid$n.trees == loop$n.trees[i] &
                     grid$interaction.depth == loop$interaction.depth[i] &
                     grid$shrinkage == loop$shrinkage[i] &
                     grid$n.minobsinnode == loop$n.minobsinnode[i])
    cuts <- grid[index, "threshold"]
    submodels[[i]] <- data.frame(threshold = cuts[cuts != loop$threshold[i]])
  }
  list(loop = loop, submodels = submodels)
}

## Fit the model independent of the threshold parameter
customGBM$fit = function(x, y, wts, param, lev, last, classProbs, ...) {
  theDots <- list(...)
  if (any(names(theDots) == "distribution")) {
    modDist <- theDots$distribution
    theDots$distribution <- NULL
  } else {
    if (is.numeric(y)) {
      stop("This works only for 2-class classification problems")
      } else modDist <- if (length(lev) == 2)  "bernoulli" else
        stop("This works only for 2-class classification problems")
  }
  # if (length(levels(y)) != 2)
  #   stop("This works only for 2-class problems")
  ## check to see if weights were passed in (and availible)
  if (!is.null(wts)) theDots$w <- wts
  if (is.factor(y) && length(lev) == 2) y <- ifelse(y == lev[1], 1, 0)
  modArgs <- list(x = x,
                  y = y,
                  interaction.depth = param$interaction.depth,
                  n.trees = param$n.trees,
                  shrinkage = param$shrinkage,
                  n.minobsinnode = param$n.minobsinnode,
                  distribution = modDist)
  do.call("gbm.fit", modArgs)
}


## Now get a probability prediction and use different thresholds to
## get the predicted class
customGBM$predict = function(modelFit, newdata, submodels = NULL) {
  out <- predict(modelFit, newdata, n.trees = modelFit$tuneValue$n.trees,
                 type = "response")#[, modelFit$obsLevels[1]]
  out[is.nan(out)] <- NA
  class1Prob <- ifelse(out >= modelFit$tuneValue$threshold,
                                modelFit$obsLevels[1],
                                modelFit$obsLevels[2])

  ## Raise the threshold for class #1 and a higher level of
  ## evidence is needed to call it class 1 so it should
  ## decrease sensitivity and increase specificity
  out <- ifelse(class1Prob >= modelFit$tuneValue$threshold,
                modelFit$obsLevels[1],
                modelFit$obsLevels[2])
  if (!is.null(submodels)) {
    tmp2 <- out
    out <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(submodels$threshold))
    out[[1]] <- tmp2
    for (i in seq(along = submodels$threshold)) {
      out[[i + 1]] <- ifelse(class1Prob >= submodels$threshold[[i]],
                             modelFit$obsLevels[1],
                             modelFit$obsLevels[2])
    }
  }
  out
}

## The probabilities are always the same but we have to create
## mulitple versions of the probs to evaluate the data across
## thresholds
customGBM$prob = function(modelFit, newdata, submodels = NULL) {
  out <- predict(modelFit, newdata, type = "response",
                 n.trees = modelFit$tuneValue$n.trees)
  out[is.nan(out)] <- NA
  out <- cbind(out, 1 - out)
  colnames(out) <- modelFit$obsLevels
  if (!is.null(submodels)) {
    tmp <- predict(modelFit, newdata, type = "response", n.trees = submodels$n.trees)
    tmp <- as.list(as.data.frame(tmp))
    lapply(tmp, function(x, lvl) {
      x <- cbind(x, 1 - x)
      colnames(x) <- lvl
      x}, lvl = modelFit$obsLevels)
    out <- c(list(out), tmp)
  }
  out
}

fourStats <- function (data, lev = levels(data$obs), model = NULL) {
  ## This code will get use the area under the ROC curve and the
  ## sensitivity and specificity values using the current candidate
  ## value of the probability threshold.
  out <- c(twoClassSummary(data, lev = levels(data$obs), model = NULL))

  ## The best possible model has sensitivity of 1 and specificity of 1. 
  ## How far are we from that value?
  coords <- matrix(c(1, 1, out["Spec"], out["Sens"]), 
                   ncol = 2, 
                   byrow = TRUE)
  colnames(coords) <- c("Spec", "Sens")
  rownames(coords) <- c("Best", "Current")
  c(out, Dist = dist(coords)[1])
}
```

And then some code showing how to use the custom model

```
set.seed(949)
trainingSet <- twoClassSim(500, -9)
mod1 <- train(Class ~ ., data = trainingSet,
              method = customGBM, metric = "Dist",
              maximize = FALSE, tuneLength = 10,
              trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 5,
                                       classProbs = TRUE,
                                       summaryFunction = fourStats))
```

The model appears to run, but finishes with the error from above. If someone could please help me with customising the GBM model to tune the GBM parameters, and the probability threshold for the classes that would be great.